# Keeping the URLs of download files to always be the same

Tags: 8, files

I have a client that need the URLs of downloadable PDF files on their site to always remain the same, because URLs of the PDF documents are published in paper written documents.

If you remove a file and then upload a new one with the same name the system will automatically add an extension (_0, _1, etc) on to the end of the file name, and keep the old file name.

This happens in multiple places - if you have the file as a field in a node, or if you add them as links via the WYSIWYG editor in text fields. Is there any way around this, so that file names always stay the same?

I know (in Drupal 7 at least) that it's possible to set up redirects, but that is cumbersome when you have 100's of files. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Well so much for my idea.

Comment: use hook_node_update. Get the uri and name of the file. Do if statement if name ends in _0 or _1, then [unlink()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp) to delete the old copy and use [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to remove the _0 or _1 from the new copy

Comment: Thanks, yes I've used the code here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2648816